# when create instance from class get error "Input string was not in a correct format." asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

first i create a class whit this property in asp.net mvc project

```
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "وارد کردن {0} الزامی می‌باشد.")]
    [DisplayName("عنوان")]
    [Display(Name = "عنوان")]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "حداکثر مقدار مجاز 100 کارکتر می باشد.")]
    public string Titr { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "وارد کردن {0} الزامی می‌باشد.")]
    [DisplayName("سربرگ")]
    [Display(Name = "سربرگ")]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "حداکثر مقدار مجاز 100 کارکتر می باشد.")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "وارد کردن {0} الزامی می‌باشد.")]
    [DisplayName("خلاصه")]
    [Display(Name = "خلاصه")]
    [MaxLength(300, ErrorMessage = "حداکثر مقدار مجاز 300 کارکتر می باشد.")]
    public string Summary { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "وارد کردن {0} الزامی می‌باشد.")]
    [DisplayName("توضیحات")]
    [Display(Name = "توضیحات")]
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "وارد کردن {0} الزامی می‌باشد.")]
    [DisplayName("دسته بندی")]
    [Display(Name = "دسته بندی")]
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "وارد کردن {0} الزامی می‌باشد.")]
    [DisplayName("لینک")]
    [Display(Name = "لینک")]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "حداکثر مقدار مجاز 100 کارکتر می باشد.")]
    public string Url { get; set; }


    [DisplayName("لینک کوتاه")]
    [Display(Name = "لینک کوتاه")]
    [MaxLength(10, ErrorMessage = "حداکثر مقدار مجاز 10 کارکتر می باشد.")]
    public string ShortUrl { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "وارد کردن {0} الزامی می‌باشد.")]
    [DisplayName("تاریخ")]
    [Display(Name = "تاریخ")]
    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "وارد کردن {0} الزامی می‌باشد.")]
    [DisplayName("نویسنده")]
    [Display(Name = "نویسنده")]
    public string AuthorId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("تصویر اصلی")]
    [Display(Name = "تصویر اصلی")]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "حداکثر مقدار مجاز 100 کارکتر می باشد.")]
    [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
    public string Image_base { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("تصویر بندانگشتی")]
    [Display(Name = "تصویر بندانگشتی")]
    [MaxLength(100, ErrorMessage = "حداکثر مقدار مجاز 100 کارکتر می باشد.")]
    [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
    public string Image_thumbnail { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "وارد کردن {0} الزامی می‌باشد.")]
    [DisplayName("وضعیت")]
    [Display(Name = "وضعیت")]
    public PostStatus Status { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser Author { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tag_Post> Tags_Post { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    public Post()
    {

    }

    public Post(string titr, string title, string summery, string description, string url, DateTime date, string authorId, PostStatus status, int categoryId)
    {
        Title = title;
        Titr = titr;
        Summary = summery;
        Description = description;
        Url = url;
        Date = date;
        AuthorId = authorId;
        Status = status;
        CategoryId = categoryId;
    }
```

then i create database with code first! now in my controller when create instance from this class i get error. error message show in catch this message `Input string was not in a correct format.here`

i use visual studio 2019 & my target framework is .net 4.7.2
It is worth mentioning that I also made two constructor, but neither of them worked.

Comment: Interestingly, I see your code look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M92UD.jpg even though when I paste the code it looks correct. I wonder if some mix of LTR and RTL is getting lost - try taking out the {0} and see if the error goes away? `[Required(ErrorMessage = "وارد کردن {0} الزامی می‌باشد.")]`

Comment: i try without `{0}` but don't work and my another class work successfully. for example, the category class, which is related to this class.category class includes `{0}` code